# C++ temporary variable lifespan shortened by binding to a reference member?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, lifetime

Until this point, I've run on the assumption that a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* that contains it.  I recently came across section [class.temporary]/5 of the spec which talks about exceptions which occur when the temporary is assigned to a reference.  For the most part, this appears to always extend the life of the temporary variable except in one special case in [[class.temporary]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary#5):

> - **A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.**
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

If I am reading this, this indicates that the lifespan of such an object can be shorter than the *full-expression* if a constructor references it.

A case study:

```
struct A
{
   A(int);
   ~A();

};

struct B
{
    B(const A& a)
    : memberRef(a)
    { }

    ~B();

    const A& memberRef;
};

// Just a few operators to use in my full expression
int operator+(const A&, const A&);
int operator+(const A&, const B&);

void testCase()
{
   int case1 = A(1) + A(2);
   int case2 = A(3) + B(A(4));
}
```

I have given each `A` constructor a different argument to make it easy to refer to the temporary variables created as *A1*, *A2*, *A3*, and *BA4*.

In case1, *A1* and *A2* get constructed in any order, then the addition occurs.  The lifespans of *A1* and *A2* are governed by the rules for reference parameters to a function call.  They are extended to the full expression containing the addition operator.

The destructors must be called in the opposite order, also in [class.temporary]/5:

> If the lifetime of two or more temporaries to which references are bound ends at the same point, these temporaries
>   are destroyed at that point in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.

So this tells me that the destructors for these objects must be called in either *A1*, *A2* or *A2*, *A1*, depending on the order the compiler chose to construct the objects.  So far so good.

The troublesome case for me is case2.  If I read this correctly, because *A4* is bound to a reference passed to `B::B(const A&)`, its lifespan now ends at the end of that constructor, **rather than the end of the expression**.

This suggests to me that destructors may be called *A4*, *A3*, *BA4* or *A4*, *BA4*, *A3*.  However the destructor for *A4* must always come first, because it occurs at the end of the constructor for *BA4*, rather than at the end of the full expression.

It suggests that it is impossible for the destructors to be called in the order *A3*, *BA4*, *A4* because *A4*'s lifespan needs to be shortened.

**Am I reading the spec correctly?**  If so, what is the rationale for this rule?  It seems more natural to me to make the temporaries passed to constructors live as long as temporaries passed to function calls, but it looks like the spec writers took effort to make the rules otherwise.

Comment: I don't think the rule you're citing applies. You're binding a reference to a reference member, not a temporary to a reference member.

Comment: @melpomene Ahh, that would be a reading I didn't think of.  If I'm understanding you correctly, if my constructor read `B(const A& a): memberRef(A(42)) { }`, then *A42*'s lifespan would be the thing that is modified to extend to the end of the constructor?

Comment: B's ctor-initializer is not binding to a temporary, it's binding to a reference parameter . By "a temporary bound to a reference member" it means the reference member being initialized by a prvalue that materializes a temporary

Comment: I think there's an important distinction between "binding a reference to an expression" and "binding a reference to an object". Unfortunately, the Standard itself is very sloppy about mixing these two ideas in many contexts.

Comment: @aschepler Where is the standard sloppy about mixing these two ideas?

Comment: @Barry Actually, the current draft may be much better now than I remembered. In particular, the same paragraph 6 quoted in this question now has new content clearly explaining how the temporary lifetime extension relates to rules on expressions. N4659 just had "when a reference is bound to a temporary", which could be read either way....

Comment: @Barry ... But then there are still things like [dcl.init.ref]/(5.1.2) "the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the object)." Here "expression lvalue" is an expression, "lvalue result of the conversion" probably means the invented expression calling a conversion function (or is it the result of the lvalue, which is an object?), and the part about base classes is suddenly about objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong bullet between the two.

[This one](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary#5.1):

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's *ctor-initializer* ([class.base.init]) persists until the constructor exits.

does not apply here. We don't have a temporary bound to a reference member in a *ctor-initializer*. That situation would be more like:

```
struct B
{
    B()
    : memberRef(A(2)) // <== 
    { }

    ~B();

    const A& memberRef;
};
```

Our situation is exactly [this one](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary#5.2):

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the *full-expression* containing the call.

We have a temporary (`A(4)`) bound to a reference parameter in a constructor (a constructor call is still a function call, the parameter we're binding to is the `a` in `B(const A& a)`), so the temporary persists until the completion of the *full-expression*.

---

In other words, there are no dangling references in what you've shown. All of these rules around binding temporaries to references are about lifetime *extension*. None of them shorten lifetimes.